# CSS selectors matches more items with the same id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using Razor and partial views to create a read email functionality in my MVC project. I am simulating a Tab navigation through my site and at a moment can appear more than one instance of the same view ( content of email that I want to read) as it is shown below.

```
<div id="MainContainer" class="contentBg">
     <div id="d2773254">
          <div id="divEmail"> .... </div>
     </div>
     <div id="d2342353" style="display:none">
          <div id="divEmail"> .... </div>
     </div>
     ...
</div>
```

My css selectors use only references to "divEmail" and all children of this div. Problem appear when are more then one HTML items in page that matches the selector.

I also tried to prepend the new div to be the first matched item from the top of the page. It works on 80% of cases, and that's why I'm searching for a solution for this problem. I  want to change all of my selectors (add a top level selector $('#divEmail').parent()) to guarantee that HTML element matched is unique.

Is there another solution? 
          Thanks a lot

Comment: Just an advice: don't use same ID for more than one element. Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: d2773254 and d2342353 from my sample is the same instance (result of an action-> Partial View) that is added into my MainContainer div. All I need is a new approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may not use the same ID twice under any circumstances. So the behavior if you do can be totally random.

In your case use `class="divEmail"` instead.

Comment: I know but this change in main navigation appears unexpected and I'm searching for a quick solution.